# How to prevent sql:variable being rounded in xml.modify() when inserting some node?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert new node to xml variable, this new node contains value of some numeric variable. Value of that numeric variable is rounded in resulting xml.

Here's my example code:

`declare @param numeric(19, 15) = 0.000000000012345;
declare @xml xml = '<params/>';
set @xml.modify('insert <param>{sql:variable("@param")}</param> into (params)[1]');
select @param as [param], @xml as [params];`

I would like to have exact numeric value in resulting xml.

Comment: There are no exact factional numbers in computers. Some data types can represent fractions better (to a higher degree of precision) than others, like the `NUMERIC` data type in SQL, but precision is always limited. The most common way to store fractional values is the IEEE 754 floating point data type, which is also used in XPath/XQuery, and it is notoriously imprecise with small fractions. Avoid storing small fractions in this data type.

Comment: I know there is no exact fractional numbers. What I want, is the same precision in xml representation as in numeric variable.

Comment: You can't, because SQL's NUMERIC and the IEEE float are incompatible to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be to convert the numeric value to string prior passing it to the modify function:

```
declare @param numeric(19, 15) = 0.000000000012345;
declare @paramString nvarchar(max) = convert(nvarchar(max), @param);
declare @xml xml = '<params/>';
set @xml.modify('insert <param>{sql:variable("@paramString")}</param> into (params)[1]');
select @param as [param], @paramString as [paramString], @xml as [params];
```

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, but I would prefer solution without intermediate step because I have dozen variables to put into xml, so your solution would require a lot of additional lines of code.

Comment: You are right, it requires additional code, but you'll have control over it, while you have limited control over the built-in sql:variale or sql:column functions. It seems (not confirmed, I did not find anything in docs) that sql:variable maps decimal to float thus you'll have rounding errors. You don't have to convert everything, string and integer values seems to be mapped/handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks, with no inline solution, yours is the best I can get.